# Routing in Express/Node.js using multiple callbacks

Tags: node.js, routes, express, middleware

I'm new to Node.js, or even JavaScript in general, and I'm currently setting up a http-server using Node/Express that should query a postgresql database. I am unsure if I'm using the routing and multiple callbacks correct, and hope someone can clarify this a bit.

Right now, it looks like this:

In my **web.js**

```
var routes = require('./routes');
app.get('/get/user/:userid', routes.user, routes.dbquery);
```

and in **routes/index.js**

```
exports.user = function(request, response, next) {
    request.querystring = "select * from users where userid = " + request.param('userid');
    next();
};

exports.dbquery = function(request, response) {
    pg.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, function(err, client, done) {
        var query = client.query(request.querystring);  
        query.on('row', function(row, result) {
            result.addRow(row);
        });
        query.on('end', function(result) {
            response.send(JSON.stringify(result.rows));
        });
        done();
    });
};
```

It works, but is this the correct way to set up routing? Specifically, is it ok to just pass on variables like the query string inside the request variable? Or is there some other, preferred solution to this?

The reason I want to do it is because I want to be able to reuse the dbquery function, since I will have multiple routes which will query the database.

Comment: Looks okay to me, although I'd use placeholders instead of string concatenation for building a query.

Comment: why are you using middle-ware to generate query? why not do it directly in dbquery any specific reason for that?

Comment: @khurrumqureshi because i want other querys and i don't want to duplicate the code in dbquery. or do you mean i should build the query directly from parameters instead?

Comment: yah you can simply build query directly from param rather to build in middle-ware than access it through request object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can attach anything you want to `request` object ( and this is a common practice ). However data there should be related to the request only, while your query is not really related to the request only ( except for `userid` ).

So how about instead of defining query in middleware just define external function:

```
var get_query = function(userid) {
    // NOTE: You should validate userid!!!
    return client.query("select * from users where userid = " + userid);
};
```

and call it in your `dbquery` route? And only attach `userid` to `request`.

Comment: thank you @freakish. any ideas how to make this reusabale for different queries though?

Comment: @erikhaq Depends on queries. You might want to use some proper ORM. I'm sure there are ORM's for PostgreSQL. Search for them.